# Set the StatusBar color through theme.?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, styles, statusbar

I am going to change the statusbar color through the `styles.xml` but can't set the statusbar color. I don't want to set the color of status bar through the coding, i only want through the `theme/style`.

**Activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="eazitouk.eazitoclient.mainclasses.TestActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_test" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
        android:name="eazitouk.eazitoclient.miscs.AppController"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launchicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="ColorPrimary">#df4a43</color>
    <color name="ColorPrimaryDark">#c8423c</color>

    <color name="ColorPrimary1">#FFCF3B</color>
    <color name="ColorPrimaryLight">#F3A2A0</color>
    <color name="ColorPrimaryLightShade">#e56e66</color>

</resources>
```

**Style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/accentcolor</item>-->
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my style.xml and AppTheme is apply to application and AppTheme1 Apply to my activity but can't set the statusbar color

Comment: Have you set color in colors.xml?

Comment: Yes i set. But cant working.

Comment: @akhil batlawala which device are you testing ??

Comment: which version in it. like `LolliPop` or `MarshMallow`. Or Like `APi level 21`or `Api level 20`.

Comment: Android 6.0,  API 23 @Ironman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tested your code. Now Change to this you have problem in your `style`. So follow my way to get Output.

**Android manifest.xml.**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="primaryColor">#EF6C00</color>
    <color name="primaryColorDark">#E65100</color>
    <color name="accentcolor">#0072BA</color>

</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accentcolor</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


</resources>
```

**styles.xml(v21)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**finally Output :**

[image]

and I more thing Keep in mind that You have set `targetSdkVersion 23`.

Comment: @akhil batlawala hey `CGPIT` did you solve it or not ??

Comment: Application gonna unfortunately stop.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eazitouk.eazitoclient/eazitouk.eazitoclient.mainclasses.Dashboard}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Answer (score 1):

just try to give color in the hexa codes. It seems that the color `ColorPrimaryDark` in `color.xml` file is not containing the color that you want.

Try:

```
<style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#fad</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Use your color code on the place of `#fad`

Comment: You have to give color code in the style.xml file, directly to the item tag.

Answer (score 0):

ColorPrimaryDark is the one corresponding for the status bar color.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

So :

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
```

Add to colors.xml your desired color with name ColorPrimaryDark

Comment: Ya i know but can't working. Please give me another solution.

Comment: You dont have your color in colors.xml or neither of your AppTheme or AppTheme1 is selected.

Comment: Edit your question and add colors.xml please. Also how do you mean this
"AppTheme is apply to application and AppTheme1 Apply to my activity but can't set the statusbar color" ?

Comment: Please check my question

Comment: AppTheme apply to application means apply to whole application and AppTheme1 to my activity means apply to individual activity.

Answer (score 0):

For change status bar color you required api level 19 and greater than 21.
    More information Please check this link.
    http://androidmysolution.blogspot.in/2015/12/change-status-bar-color-for-your.html